# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$Email' (T_VARIABLE) on line 19

Tags: php

Hi Guys i keep getting this error and have no idea on how to solve it.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$Email' (T_VARIABLE)  on line 19.

here is a bit of the coding

```
$Telephone# = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Telephone#']);

$Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);<--ERROR HERE

$Vetter = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Vetter']);
```

Comment: Sidenote: Use a prepared statement, it's safer than `real_escape_string()`, believe me when I say this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on line above in line

```
$Telephone# = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Telephone#']);
```

The `#` will comment out the rest leaving this for the parser:

```
$Telephone $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
```

So just remove the `#`

Comment: Any basic editor would syntax-highlight this to clearly show the issue. Even the code on here is colour-coded to show it's a comment and therefore something's wrong. So either the OP isn't using even a basic code editor (notepad.exe??) or didn't bother to notice...